# Is Hilary my sister or brother?

Tags: commas, gender, restrictive-clauses

I came across this question while taking an English grammar test on the BBC news magazine. The multiple choice question is based on the following sentence:

> "I'd like to introduce you to my sister Clara, who lives in Madrid, to
>   Benedict, my brother who doesn't, and to my only other sibling,
>   Hilary."

Which of the following is correct?

1. Hilary is male
2. Hilary is female
3. Impossible to say from the given context

As it turns out, Hilary is *male*. But can someone explain why? Per my thinking, it should've been *impossible to say from the given context*.

I say this because:

> my sister Clara, who lives in Madrid

From this we know that Clara is female and she lives in Madrid

> to Benedict, my brother who doesn't,

I thought this meant- Benedict is the brother who doesn't live in Madrid

And last,

> and to my only other sibling, Hilary.

which doesn't specify whether Hilary is male or female. It just says- "*only sibling*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> to Benedict, my brother who doesn't,

This is the clue. If it would have been

> to Benedict, my brother, who doesn't,

Then he may have been the only brother the speaker has.

However, because there is no comma, the *who doesn't* is *restrictive*: in this case it describes an essential property of *this specific brother*. Since there is such a description for *that specific brother*, being the *brother who doesn't live in Madrid*, it follows there has to be another brother.

Since it is clearly stated there is only one other sibling, that sibling has to be male as well.

So not only do we know that Hilary is male, we know where he lives!

(Sorry for the earlier confusion. For more information on restrictive / non-restrictive clauses, have a look [here](https://www.butte.edu/departments/cas/tipsheets/grammar/relative_pronouns.html).)

Comment: _Since it is clearly stated there is only one other sibling, that sibling has to be male as well_. I've read your answer several times, but I'm still as puzzled and lost as ever.

Comment: I disagree. This is a test question, and is therefore not speaking like a normal person, it is trying to find out a person's understand of English. 'Hilary' is both a male and female name. 'Sibling' means 'brother' or 'sister'. To my mind it's deliberately neutral so the answer should (3) Impossible to say from the given context. Otherwise why not say ".. and to my other brother Hilary." (which is what most normal people would say, specifically to *remove* the ambiguity).

Comment: @Mynamite *why not say ... which is what most normal people would say*? Because *this is a test question, and is therefore not speaking like a normal person*. You're right that *Hilary* and *sibling* are neutral (and deliberately so, to make the testee examine the grammar), but the gender is indeterminate only if there are no other indicators, and in this case, there are.

Comment: @J.R. Try forgetting about the sister. You are talking about two siblings of unknown gender with someone else. That person points to someone walking past and says, "That's the brother who lives in Madrid." Do you now know the gender of the other sibling? Yes, because you can infer that there's another brother who doesn't live in Madrid, because of the restrictive clause. The rest of the question is just distraction from this point.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm with @J.R. here. I've gone through the answer _several_ times, but it still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @J.R. From _the brother that doesn't live in Madrid_, we know there is another brother. Apart from Clara and Benedict, there is just one other sibling, Hilary. That one sibling has to be the brother. If there was no mention that Hilary is the only other sibling, there could be another brother (Jake), and Hilary could be either male or female.

Comment: @Mynamite Especially _because_ this is a test question, one is supposed to study the grammar in detail. And there is a significant difference between "Benedict who doesn't" and "Benedict, who doesn't". This _test_ question _tests_ whether one understands that difference. If you see the difference between the two, simple logic leads to Hilary being male.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to clarify. I think it's worth pointing out that this reads more like a brain teaser than something most native speakers would naturally pick up on. I'm glad I wasn't the only one who struggled with this!

Comment: This is definitely just a grammar trick or brainteaser, and I think most native English speakers would only infer that Hilary is a brother if they had been warned that this is a grammar puzzle. It wouldn't be safe to do so otherwise, because it's unlikely that the speaker or writer is being so picky with their grammar!

Comment: In David Crystal's The Fight for English almost this exact quote is given as an example of the over-complex sentences certain grammarians construct to demonstrate how bad everyone but them are at grammar.